# Is a "how should these experimental results be interpreted?" question admissible?

Tags: discussion, scope

I can't remember seeing posts about the interpretation of experimental results on SE, so I am not sure whether such a question is SE-legitimate. Concretely, after reading some rather old and largely forgotten/ignored experimental papers about organic [high-temperature superconductors](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/High-temperature_superconductivity), I wondered and am still wondering whether a widely-cited theoretical model might be applied to them. To my knowledge, the connection has not been discussed in what little relevant literature there is, hence the question concerning the experimental results arises naturally. I am asking here first because formulating it in a meaningful way would require some work and I am not sure it would be deemed acceptable. If not, why not?

Comment: Does "forgotten/ignored" means fake discovery? Because there's hardly any actual hi temp. organic superconductor...

Answer (score 13, accepted):

I think the specific question you seem to have in mind here - "can the results of X be explained with theory Y?" - is perfectly on-topic, as long as X and Y are parts of mainstream physics.

Broader questions about interpretations of experimental results (like "Here's a dataset, please explain it") might be more difficult to ask, in particular as they become closer to original research.

Comment: There is perhaps a potential issue with homework-like aspects of this.

Comment: Unfortunately it's rather non-mainstream aspect https://physics.stackexchange.com/questions/700068/littles-model-for-superconducting-oxidized-atactic-polypropylene